# Django Admin in Angularjs

Tags: django, angularjs, django-admin, single-page-application, django-rest-framework

I'm converting my Django projects front end from using jquery to [angularjs](http://angularjs.org) with [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) in order to help make it a single page application. I've gotten most of my trickier pages converted over with angular and now comes the battle with Django's admin page.

I love the built in admin feature of Django and my users use it daily so I want to replicate it as close as possible. I haven't found any packages that relate to this so I was going to bite the bullet and just start making it from scratch. Before I start the tedious process I wanted to see if anyone else has had a similar task and what they did to accomplish it. Maybe someone knows the best practice way of going about it?

My plan is to make a reusable controller based upon the model that is shown in the URL (`admin/app/model`) to show the `change_list` and `change_form` views of django-admin. I'm new to angularjs so I may not be fully be aware of the best way to do this.

Once I build this out I'll post it up on githhub.

**UPDATE**
I have created a github repository after working on this for a little while now. It is still very raw and does not work 100%. If you're interested in it or want to help out, here you go: https://github.com/austinhuminski/angular-django-admin

Comment: Were you able to finish this completely? We are trying to achieve the same thing, but I am scared that it'll take a lot of time trying to rebuild all the Django admin features from scratch. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

ng-admin is a pure Angular.js implementation of an admin interface based on a RESTful webservice. In addition to basic CRUD, it supports relationships, search, a dashobard, and custom field types.

https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin

It doesn't replicate the Django admin, but tries to build up on Bootstrap and Angular.js for a rich client-side admin experience.

Disclaimer: we wrote it.

Comment: And in case you're looking for a react.js equivalent, check out admin-on-rest: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great idea, and the same thing occurred to me a little while ago, which led me here!

It's something I'd be interested in building myself. I think it would be quite a big task, and one of the major challenges would be to replicate all the functionality of the django ModelAdmin types in angular. Not to say this couldn't be done.

As for suggestions - It's got to be a TDD led project, both on the angular side and with django (luckily both projects are very much built with testing in mind).

For django REST integration, I personally would probably look at django-tastypie, but mainly just because I'm familiar with it and like using it over the other django REST frameworks.

Sounds like an excellent idea overall - I'll race you :)

Comment: Happy to see I'm not the only one interested! I have done a decent amount of work on this already. I have date hierarchy, pagination,  and filtering completed all with back button functionality and updating the URL. I elected for going with Django Rest Framework as I had no familiarity with tastypie. Agreed that it needs to be heavily testable which I'm sadly very lazy with. I'll try to get my code uploaded to github shortly so you can take a look at what I have thus far and perhaps collaborate.

Comment: Cool! I'd be very interested in helping out if I can

Comment: Here is the link if your interested. Need to do a lot of cleanup but figure I'd put it up a little early. https://github.com/austinhuminski/angular-django-admin

Comment: Added README to repository.

Comment: Great, looks very interesting, ill clone it down later and have a proper look. My initial thought was to subclass the admin.AdminSite for this project, in the hope that the regular ModelAdmin classes could be re-used without requiring any changes by the end user. That would also give you all the setip for field exclusions and ordering too. I do like the approach you've taken though, ill take a good look later and see if i can help